# What is the difference between "$(this)" and "this"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was reading the http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery. And got confused with use of `this` in these 2 code segments.

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#orderedlist").find("li").each(function(i) {
        $(this).append( " BAM! " + i );
       });
     });

    $(document).ready(function() {
      // use this to reset several forms at once
       $("#reset").click(function() {
        $("form").each(function() {
         this.reset();
        });
     });
   });
```

When do we need `$(this)` and `this`?  And what is the difference between them? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between “this”, “$this” and “$(this)”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889570/what-is-the-difference-between-this-this-and-this)

Comment: @patrick: I don't think it's a duplicate. It's worth answering why `$(this)` is needed in one part of this particular code while `this` is needed in a different part.

Comment: @mblase75: Well, I guess I disagree. That answer, coupled with what the tutorial already explains makes it a duplicate. Reading the answers to the other question should solve it. From the tutorial: *"Note that in an `.each()` function, `this` refers to the actual element."*

Comment: ...or if you don't like that duplicate, here's one that references the same code in the same tutorial: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur quick responses. @patrick take it easy man. I'm trying to learn something and people are just helping me. You might be in that stage at some point.

Comment: @gmail user: Take it easy? [This is how StackOverflow works.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) It is expected that you've done some basic research first and searched the site to see if the question already exists. That's why StackOverflow bombards you with possible duplicate questions while you're creating the post. You should be searching through those to see if the question has already been asked and answered. Don't take it personally.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`this` refers to the DOM element itself; `$(this)` wraps the element up in a jQuery object.

In the first example, you need `$(this)` because `.append()` is a jQuery method.

In the second example, `reset()` is a JavaScript method, so no jQuery wrapper is needed.

Answer (score 7):

`this` by itself is just a regular object.

`$(this)` takes `this` and adds the jQuery wrapper so you can use the jQuery methods with the object.

Answer (score 3):

`this` refers to a DOM object. So `reset()` is a function of a form DOM object. `append()` on the other hand is a jQuery method so it has to be called by a jQuery object, hence the `$(this)`.

When you surround `this` with `$`, you get a jQuery object back representing that DOM object.

Answer (score 2):

Generally in jQuery, `this` will be an instance of the DOM element in question, and `$(this)` builds a jQuery object around `this` which gives you the usual jQuery methods like `each()` and `val()`.

Answer (score 1):

you only need $(this) if you are following it with a jquery function on the same line of code.

```
ex: $(this).find(...);    $(this).val();   etc
```

or else you only need `this`.