# Select/Unselect Text on click Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I want to create the following behavior in IE9:

Clicking on the textbox will select the text from the textbox. Clicking on it again will unselect the text.

I tried the following from this linK: http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=105530

```
var x = 2;

function selectIt(obj)
{
    if (x % 2 == 0)
    {
        obj.select();
    }
    else
    {
        if (document.selection)
        {
            document.selection.empty();
            obj.blur();
        }
        else
        {
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        }
    }
    obj.focus();
    x++;
}
```

I also used this: http://jsfiddle.net/HmQxZ/1/

But the above solutions have weird behaviors when applied to several textboxes. What is the best way to approach this kind of problem. Is it possible to do this without using a global variable?

**UPDATE:**

The fiddle works in Chrome. But it does not work in IE9. In IE9, the text is selected but when you click on the textbox again, the text is not unselected/unhighlighted. In Chrome, the second click unselects/unhighlights the text.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with several text boxes would be that your `x` variable is global. You'd need a separate `x` variable per textbox.

You could use a map:

```
var x = {};

function selectIt(obj)
{
    var key = ... <-- get name (or id) of textbox from obj somehow to use as key in map
    if (!x.hasOwnProperty(key)) x[key] = 0;
    if (x[key] % 2 == 0)
    {
        obj.select();
    }
    else
    {
        if (document.selection)
        {
            document.selection.empty();
            obj.blur();
        }
        else
        {
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        }
    }
    obj.focus();
    x[key]++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Ridcully. I do understand that which is why I am asking if it is possible to do so without the use of a global variable. My form contains several textboxes having the same behavior. I would like to know the best way to do this.

Comment: Basically I would suggest to check if anything is selected of the textbox clicked -- if so, unselect everything, if not, select everything. But, according to jquery's documentation of the select() function, checking for a selected part is depending on the browser (The method for retrieving the current selected text differs from one browser to another. A number of jQuery plug-ins offer cross-platform solutions.), so either you use one of those plugins or you use a variation of your original code with the x variable.

Comment: @nmengo I added an example using a map for x.

Comment: Thanks. This was not exactly what I was looking for. But I think it is a good enough answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Chrome - there is a [toggle event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) function in jQuery but it is not needed in this case

```
$('input').click(function() {
 // the select() function on the DOM element will do what you want
 this.select();
});
```

​
but I suggest you tell the script which types of fields you want to select

```
$("input[type=text], input[type=url]").click(function() {
  $(this).select(); // "this" is native JS 
});
```

​[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/fU83Y/)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I need it in IE9. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: It highlights the textbox, but when I click on it again, it does not unselect/unhighlight. In Chrome, select/unselect is possible.

Comment: I would suggest using `$(this)` over this. Not that it wouldn't work otherwise, but it gives you more options when you need them. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889570/what-is-the-difference-between-this-this-and-this

Answer (score 0):

[Try this Demo](http://jsbin.com/welcome/22843/edit)

DEMO jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $("input[type='Text']").on("click",function(){
     if (typeof this.selectionStart == "number") 
         this.select();
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your complete solution.

**Demo** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp79

**HTML**

```
<div id="panel">
  <input type="text" value="Click Me to Select Text" />
  <input type="text" value="Click Me to Select Text" />
  <input type="text" value="Click Me to Select Text" />
  <input type="text" value="Click Me to Select Text" />
  <input type="text" value="Click Me to Select Text" />
  <input type="text" value="Click Me to Select Text" />
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $("#panel input[type=text]").click(function() {
        $(this).select();
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
input{
  display:block;
  border:1px solid #333;
  background:#efefef;
  margin-top:15px;
  padding:3px;
}
```

**Demo** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp79

Comment: EXACTLY the same solution as mine and it STILL does not work in IE