# Can I toggle specific instances of a class that occurs multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a working mockup of a site design and I want the ad spaces to disappear to illustrate what the page would look like if they're empty.  Can I accomplish this without having the uniquely identify each space?  I was hoping this would work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.adSpace').click(function() {
    $this.toggle('fast');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `$this` is not defined here. The [jQuery tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery#Find_me:_Using_selectors_and_events) provides a good introduction to event handling, with examples. It's worth a read (and that's what it is there for: to get you started).

Comment: This should be worth reading : [what-is-the-difference-between-this-$this-and-$(this)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889570/what-is-the-difference-between-this-this-and-this)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `$(this)` instead of `$this`. $this is not defined here.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPtzR/)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.adSpace').click(function() {
       $(this).toggle('fast');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

`$this` is not the object. You should use  `$(this)`.

`this` : **java-script object**

`$(this)` : **converting this to jQuery object**

You can use

```
$('.adSpace').click(function() {
   $(this).toggle('fast');
});
```