# jQuery "this" and element collection

Tags: jquery, this

In this piece of code:

```
    $(function() {
        $("div").click(function() {
            $(this).before("<p>Hi</p>");

        });
    });
```

What does 'this' actually refer to? 
Does it refer to the whole list of divs, or just to the specific one clicked? And how can I know?

Also, would it matter if I wrote `this` without the jQuery sign or are they the same?

Comment: Don't forget to make use of console.log to check the value of any variables you aren't sure of, it will save you a lot of time

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to jQuery and that didn't come to mind.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery $(this) vs this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this) or may be [$(this)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889570/what-is-the-difference-between-this-this-and-this)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within the click handler, `this` is a reference to the single DOM Element which fired the event—in this case the div element. By wrapping it in `$()` you create a jQuery reference to that div element (a jQuery object containing that single element, allowing you to call jQuery methods on it.

```
$(function() {
    $("div").click(function() {
        $(this).before("<p>Hi</p>"); // 'this' is an HTMLDivElement

    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

this is the DOM object, whereas $(this) is the jQuery wrapper around same.

When using this, you can call DOM methods on it, but not jQuery methods. When using                    $(this), you can call jQuery methods on it, but not DOM methods.

Answer (score 2):

`this` is always the specific DOM node with which you're interacting, wherease `$(this)` is the same DOM node, but wrapped in a jQuery object.

The difference is that `this` can be used with plain JavaScript/DOM API (and `$(this)` cannot), whereas, if you need to use jQuery methods (`hide()`, `show()`, etc...), then you'll need to use `$(this)` (and not `this`).

Answer (score 2):

`this` is just a reference. The language reads it as taking in the most currently active element.

It can be used throughout your code to enable many tasks to take a range of variables that are dependent on the current session.

> In many object-oriented programming languages, this (or self) is a keyword which can be used in instance methods to refer to the object on which the currently executing method has been invoked.

[take a look at this.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_%28computer_science%29)

Answer (score 1):

`$(this)` refers to the jQuery object created from the selector you attached the event handler too. Any `div` element the event is performed on becomes `this` along with the added properties and methods created from being a jQuery object

Answer (score 0):

In this circumstance, `this` refers to the particular HTML element you have clicked.

No you need to put '$' sign before `(this)`, or else it will result in JavaScript errors.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery `$(this)[0]` is the same as using `this` in Javascript.

So `$(this)[0] == this`.

Comment: ... *but what is `this`* ;)

Comment: Obviously *this* is **this**, but clearly different to `this`. Duh!

Answer (score 0):

Copied from [Nick Craver's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3889590):

> - `this` - Refers to the DOM element in the handler you're currently on, but this may be another object entirely in other situations, but it's always the context.
> - `$this` - Usually created by `var $this = $(this)` a cached version of the jQuery wrapped version for efficiency (or chain off `$(this)` to get the same in many cases).
> - `$(this)` - The jQuery wrapped version of the element, so you have access to all its methods (the ones in `$.fn specifically`).

Comment: Next time you copy and paste someone elses answer, I would be careful to make it *explicitly* clear your answer is a copy and paste; plagiarism is taken *very* seriously on Stack Overflow (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78658/is-it-okay-to-copy-paste-answers-from-other-questions).

Comment: i apologize for my error, i copy and pasted nick Craver but i also wrote that was his answer

Comment: I appreciate there was a link to his answer in your post, but like I said; you need to make it ***explicitly*** clear that your answer is copied from his; otherwise it could be interpreted as a link to further reading.